# mismatching topics ar_track_alvar_msgs

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings~

While trying to reach position/orientation of detected marker, getting this kind of error:

```
[ERROR] [1544117434.771301999]: Client [/vision_node] wants topic /ar_pose_marker to have datatype/md5sum [ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarker/ef2b6ad42bcb18e16b22fefb5c0fb85f], but our version has [ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarkers/943fe17bfb0b4ea7890368d0b25ad0ad]. Dropping connection.
```

I do understand an issue, which is I'm using another structure of msg in vision_node, than ar_track_alvar advertiser.

In this case, how could I get a header on 'pose' of marker detected.

Note: I believe, ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarkers is done to detect a bunch of markers, but not only one. I only need to detect a single, so it doesn't matter for me, which kind of message to use.

Attaching part of /vision_node code down below:

```
Localizer(ros::NodeHandle& nh)
{
    ar_sub_ = nh.subscribe<ar_track_alvar_msgs::AlvarMarker>("ar_pose_marker", 1,
    &Localizer::visionCallback, this);

    server_ = nh.advertiseService("localize_part", &Localizer::localizePart, this);
}

void visionCallback(const ar_track_alvar_msgs::AlvarMarkerConstPtr& msg)
{
    last_msg_ = msg;
    //ROS_INFO_STREAM(last_msg_->pose.pose);
}

bool localizePart(myworkcell_core::LocalizePart::Request& req,
                  myworkcell_core::LocalizePart::Response& res)
{
  // Read last message
  ar_track_alvar_msgs::AlvarMarkerConstPtr p = last_msg_;
  if (!p) return false;

  tf::Transform cam_to_target;
  tf::poseMsgToTF(p->pose.pose, cam_to_target);

  tf::StampedTransform req_to_cam;
  listener_.lookupTransform(req.base_frame, p->header.frame_id, ros::Time(0), req_to_cam);

  tf::Transform req_to_target;
  req_to_target = req_to_cam * cam_to_target;

  tf::poseTFToMsg(req_to_target, res.pose);
  return true;
}

ros::Subscriber ar_sub_;
ar_track_alvar_msgs::AlvarMarkerConstPtr last_msg_;
ros::ServiceServer server_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;
```

Feel free to clarify, I am bad at explaining:D

[EDIT]:

LocalizePart service:

```
 #request
string base_frame
---
#response
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
```

[EDIT2]:

Found solution after checking ar_track_alvar messages available and only got this line changed:

```
  tf::poseMsgToTF(p->markers[0].pose.pose, cam_to_target);
```

Code compiled, my stupid mistake. It's not about ROS versions or package conflicts, but because there are two types of msg offered by package and I checked a wrong one.

Anyways might be helpful to other beginners to go through rosmsg structure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310166/mismatching-topics-ar_track_alvar_msgs/) by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found solution after checking ar_track_alvar messages available and only got this line changed:

```
  tf::poseMsgToTF(p->markers[0].pose.pose, cam_to_target);
```

---

Originally posted by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) with karma: 69 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use ar_track_alvar to broadcast TFs from the camera frame to the markers. Using these you can replace everything in your localizePart() function with a single lookupTransform call. This call would simply lookup the transform from the frame given in the service request to the frame of the maker.

The specific error you're getting is caused by code from different versions of ROS or the package. But I'd recommend you use the TF only approach it will be much simpler to build, and can be introspected using RVIZ.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2018-12-06**:
Thanks for your response, PeteBlackerThe3rd!
I believe, a procedure of checking for a stream of marker's messages and taking the last one is necessary by any chance.
I attached LocalizePart.srv as well.
I was trying to use message ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarkers, but cannot reach to 'pose'.